# why unity camera scrolling updates scene only after transition has finished?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make my camera scroll over my scene as the game starts. here is the code attached to my main camera

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class cameraScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public float camYLerpTime = 5000f;
    float camYInitPoint = 950f;
    public float camYEndPoint = 0f;
    float camPosY;
    //float camFieldOfViewStable = 170.5f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        camIntro ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void LateUpdate () {
        if (transform.position.y!=camYEndPoint) {
            transform.position = new Vector3 (transform.position.x, camPosY, transform.position.z);
        }
    }
    void camIntro()
    {
        camPosY = Mathf.Lerp (camYInitPoint, camYEndPoint, camYLerpTime * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

However, I only see the rendered scene as transition is finished and the camera is in it's final position. What am I doing wrong?

Project settings: 2D
Unity version: 5.1.2f1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem**

The issue here is that you're misusing `Mathf.Lerp()` in

```
void camIntro()
{
    camPosY = Mathf.Lerp (camYInitPoint, camYEndPoint, camYLerpTime * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

The third argument you supply to `Mathf.Lerp()` is given by `camYLerpTime * Time.deltaTime`. What exactly is this value? Well, you already set `camYLerpTime = 5000f`, and `Time.deltaTime` will be around ~0.0167 (assuming 60 FPS, so 1/60)

That means your third argument for `Mathf.Lerp()` will be: `5000 * ~0.0167 = ~83`. So the contents of `camIntro()` can be considered to be:

```
camPosY = Mathf.Lerp (camYInitPoint, camYEndPoint, 83);
```

Looking at the [documentation for `Mathf.Lerp()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Lerp.html), that third argument (`t`) should be between 0-1, and determines how close the returned value is to the start/end values supplied. When `t = 0`, the start value is returned, and when `t = 1`, the end value is returned. If `t > 1` (like in this case, where `t =  83`), it is clamped to 1, and so `Mathf.Lerp()` will return the end value (`camYEndPoint`).

This is why when this code executes:

```
void LateUpdate () {
    if (transform.position.y!=camYEndPoint) {
        transform.position = new Vector3 (transform.position.x, camPosY, transform.position.z);
    }
}
```

the camera is instantly snapped to the end position, because that was the value `camPosY` received from `Mathf.Lerp()` earlier.

**The solution**

So, how do we fix this? Instead of calling `Mathf.Lerp()` when `Start()` is called, let's call it in the `LateUpdate()` instead, and use a variable to track the progress of the camera movement. Assuming you want the movement to go for 5 seconds (and not 5000 seconds):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class cameraScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public float camYLerpTime = 5f;
    float camYLerpProg = 0;
    float camYInitPoint = 950f;
    public float camYEndPoint = 0f;
    float camPosY;
    //float camFieldOfViewStable = 170.5f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void LateUpdate () {
        if (transform.position.y!=camYEndPoint) {
            camYLerpProg += Time.deltaTime;
            float camPosY = Mathf.Lerp (camYInitPoint, camYEndPoint, camYLerpProg / camYLerpTime);
            transform.position = new Vector3 (transform.position.x, camPosY, transform.position.z);
        }
    }
}
```

With this revised code, the third argument of `Mathf.Lerp()` is now given by `camYLerpProg / camYLerpTime`, which is essentially (movement time elapsed / maximum movement time) and provides a value in the expected range of 0-1.

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks @Serlite, you have found all the correct answers ;)

Comment: Actually, I had already found out that the problem was with Mathf.Lerp and that the camera position's y value was never updated. So I wrote my own solution and got back here to post it as answer. Fortunately reading yours I found out that your solution was more elegant and more efficient than my own. Thanks a lot for your time and for sharing your knowledge.